# Why my cross entropy loss function does not converge?

Tags: pytorch, cross-entropy

I try to write a cross entropy loss function by myself. My loss function gives the same loss value as the official one, but when i use my loss function in the code instead of official cross entropy loss function, the code does not converge. When i use the official cross entropy loss function, the code converges. Here is my code, please give me some suggestions. Thanks very much
The input 'out' is a tensor (B*C) and 'label' contains class indices (1 * B)

```
class MylossFunc(nn.Module): 
    def __init__(self):
        super(MylossFunc, self).__init__()
    def forward(self, out, label):
        out = torch.nn.functional.softmax(out, dim=1)
            n = len(label)
            loss = torch.FloatTensor([0])
            loss = Variable(loss, requires_grad=True)
            tmp = torch.log(out)
            #print(out)
            torch.scalar_tensor(-100)
            for i in range(n):
                loss = loss  - torch.max(tmp[i][label[i]], torch.scalar_tensor(-100) )/n
            loss = torch.sum(loss)
            return loss
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `torch.softmax` and `torch.log`, you should use `torch.log_softmax`, otherwise your training will become unstable with `nan` values everywhere.

This happens because when you take the softmax of your logits using the following line:

```
out = torch.nn.functional.softmax(out, dim=1)
```

you might get a zero in one of the components of `out`, and when you follow that by applying `torch.log` it will result in `nan` (since `log(0)` is undefined). That is why torch (and other common libraries) provide a single stable operation, `log_softmax`, to avoid the numerical instabilities that occur when you use `torch.softmax` and `torch.log` individually.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I see that you are new to SO, consider upvoting useful answers and marking the answer that solved your problem as the accepted answer to help people who might have the same issue in the future see more relevant posts.

Comment: thank your kindly remind, i marked ''solved''